# how can i download a file in google cloud storage using BlobstoreService java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

Since 2 days Googling, I got to upload a file in Google Cloud Storage using java. Now I am facing troubles to download the same file from Google Cloud Storage using java.

I tried with `BlobstoreService` to upload a file. Can any body give me the suggestions to download from the GCS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read a file on Google Cloud Storage from an App Engine application, you need to use the [Google Cloud Storage Java Client Library](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/), or you can read it using [Blobstore API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/) after you get the blobstore key using the function [createGsBlobKey](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobstoreService#createGsBlobKey%28java.lang.String%29).

Using Google Cloud Storage Java Client Library in order to read/write files is fairly simple. Check out this page for more info:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/getstarted